# Iterating inside an array, using similar methods but getting different results

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I don't understand the difference between these two processes (This is all part of a bigger program):

This is the working version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    int cNumber = decNumb % 2;
    binNum[32 - i] = cNumber;
    decNumb = decNumb / 2;
}
```

and this is the version where I get the unintended result:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    int cNumber = decNum % 2;
    binNum[32-j] =cNumber;
    decNumb = decNumb / 2;
    j++;
}
```

I don't understand the difference why doing it with an extra variable `j` gives me a different result. Shouldn't both versions give me the same outcome?

Any help would be appreciated!

*edit: added missing opening bracket (typo)*

Comment: If you indented properly, you would see that the second code has a missing opening brace.

Comment: Actually, the problem is that `j` is set to 0 at the beginning of every loop. Try moving `int j = 0;` to *before* the for loop.

Comment: ah, thank you that answers my question. (The missing opening brace was a typo sorry)

Comment: @Vroryn -- Don't type in code.  Copy from your code editor and paste it in the edit window.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
int j = 0;
int cNumber = decNum % 2;
binNum[32-j] =cNumber;
decNumb = decNumb / 2;
j++;
}
```

This does not run because it does not have an open brace for the `for loop`.  In addition, `j` is reiterated and reset to 0 every loop, so you would not get your desired result.  You could have done:

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    int cNumber = decNum % 2;
    binNum[32-j] =cNumber;
    decNumb = decNumb / 2;
    j++;
}
```

Otherwise, both codes should run equally fine.

Comment: What you wrote initially wasn't correct and your second edit doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry, i missed out the braces too!  ahah

Comment: Yes, @MateenUlhaq I have added the brace